# How to make a form in a panel stop moving in VisualStudio?

Tags: c#, c++, forms, visual-studio, panel

I created **two forms** and adding **one panel** on each. The button from the first form opens the second one, and the button from the second one opens the first form. **The problem** is that whenever i press the button to see the other form, **the whole panel** moves!
This is the code i have for the both buttons.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           panel1.Controls.Clear();
           Form1 form = new Form1();
           form.TopLevel = false;
           panel1.Controls.Add(form);
           form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
           form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           form.Show();
        }
```

I also posted a gif to see the movement they do:
[movement_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm9Q5.gif)

Comment: Neither the c++ not the visual-studio tags make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the color of the whole Form like this

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0); // this is black
```

Comment: Thank you so much! No need of panel anymore. You saved my project^^